# Error in array declaration: Expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I declared a global struct with the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    int index;
}element;
```

I have a program with `k` sorted queues, and I put in a `heapSort`(I am using an array) the minimum from each one. I use the index value in struct to track the element that I want to pop out of the heap. Now, I want to test the program for different number of queues, so I did this:

```
for (int i = 10;i <= 50;i += 10) {
    const int k = i;
    element a[k];
}
```

But I get an error:

> Expression must have a constant value

Is there any way I can "trick" that?

Comment: Standard C++ does not have variable length arrays (C does).  Use std::vector instead.

Comment: You might use `std::vector<element> a(k)`.

Comment: `std::vector<element> a(i);` and throw out `k` entirely. And fyi, if allowed by whatever purpose this is for, the heap operations in `<algorithm>` will come in very handy and save you a *ton* of code. If this is for a priority queue, the [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) adapter can save you even *more* effort.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You declared an `array`, an array's size cannot be changed. To solve this issue it would be in your best interest to use a `vector`.

Try this:

```
#include <vector>
vector <element> a(50);
```

To pop elements out of the `vector` try this:

```
a.erase(a.begin()+index_from_zero);
```